# StrictModeBuilder permitAll not working

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I do have an old app that refuses to work on Android 4.1 devices. It's the NetworkOnMainThreadException that jumps in here.

So I tried to permit this with the following steps - but these don't work. I tested that with the 4.1 emulator. What is really needed to come around that error - app rewrite is no option. Currently I exclude 4.1 devices from my apps.

A class file ...

```
public class StrictModeWrapper {

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public static void checkAvailable() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static void setThreadPolicy() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy strictModeThreadPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(strictModeThreadPolicy);
    }
}
```

... called in an extended Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        try {
            StrictModeWrapper.checkAvailable();
            StrictModeWrapper.setThreadPolicy();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        }
    }
}
```

The extended Application class is registered in the Manifest and working.

Comment: how old? You must be doing some network operation on main thread.. `StrictMode` supported since API-9 and `NetworkOnMainThreadException` introduced in API-11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StrictMode behaves different on Android version >= 16 than prior releases. The docs suggest to issue StrictMode calls in onCreate() of an extended Application, Activity, etc.. At least onCreate() in an extended Application works different now and proofes the docs wrong (as of today).

Here's the StrictMode doc that describes how to add StrictMode calls to an extended application for example (that's wrong as of today):

[StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Here's a Google Code issue that describes the problem and gives a workaround:

[Google Code Issue 35298](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35298)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing seems to have changed in `StrictMode` since api 11. It must be the changes in some other android classes you used, that caused a StrictMode policy violation.

The Android documentation itself says

> "But don't feel compelled to fix everything that StrictMode finds. "

But since its a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` you must do a thorough check. See all network communications in your app, and ensure that they are not blocking your main thread.

And make sure you remove/disable the `StrictMode` code in your release build, as it is only a developer tool to identify accidental mistakes.

### Update:

Your app crashed because :

- You had not blocked the execution of StrictMode policy setting code in your release build. It should be executed only while testing.
- Something changed in the `StrictMode` class that caused the strict mode policy to reset after `onCreate`.

I have 2 questions :

1. Doesnt the crash indicate that the StrictMode policy was working? There was a policy violation and hence it crashed.
2. Doesnt it indicate that there is some network code in your app that blocks the main thread?

Comment: This is not true, definetely. Today I found an issue for 4.1.x (35298). Since JB StrictMode, set in MyApplication.onCreate() is reset after onCreate finished. This worked on Android versions prior JB. The app is a pure WLAN tool - no GPRS connectivity possible at all. I won't change that app. I will remove it from the store. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The `StrictMode` code should not be present in the release build that you upload to the store. Its just a tool for raising a warning whenever it detects a piece of code that blocks main thread. It should be blocked or removed completely before uploading to market..